# threejs rotate part of model，how part of model rotate around the part itself

Tags: three.js

I was confused， I load an obj model to html， but when I rotate part of this model(this model is from blender, part, one by one)， this part just rotate around the center of the model， but it  does not rotate arounr its center, how can I let the part rotate around the part itself, the statement "part.rotation += 1;" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to organize the parts in this way: each part is a THREE.Mesh that contain a collections of vertices that positioned (local) in relative to the part's center. in other words, the world's part center become the origin axis in the part's local axis. this mesh need to be a child of THREE.Object3D located in the center of this part. then you can apply rotation on the mesh object.

example for how to transpose vertices location:

```
mesh.position.set(partCenterVec);

mesh.updateMatrixWorld();
mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(mesh.matrixWorld);

// reset local matrix
mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
mesh.rotation.set(0,0,0);
mesh.scale.set(1,1,1);
mesh.updateMatrixWorld();
```